# Question on exterior angles of cyclic quadrilaterls

Tags: geometry, angle

Please help me with this question with figures: Prove that sum of angles in four segment of a circle exterior to cyclic quadrilateral equal to $6$ right angles. Also help me to understand this question.

Comment: Is the cyclic quadrilateral one with only 4 sides? If so it would be 4 right angles. In general with more sides the sum of exterior angles is always 360 degrees i.e. 4 right angles (not 6).

Comment: @coffeemath I don't understand this, this question appeared on my question paper.

Comment: Ayushakj: Could you include the exact statement of the question? "sum of angles in four segment of a circle exterior to cyclic quadrilateral" doesn't say how the four angles are determined, o whether the four segments are adjacent to each other going around the circle, or whether the angles mentioned are the exterior or interior angles formed.